# how is this url encoded?

Tags: javascript, url, uri

```
http://*.uservoice.com/track.gif?AyJjbGllaNRfaWQiOjI3NDMxLCJzb3VyY2UiOiJ3aWTnZXQyIiwic3ViZG9tYWluX2lkRjo5MzgzOSwiaG9zdCI6ImtpdHRlEnNmb3JzYWxlLn8zZXJ2b4ljZS5jb20ifQ%3D%3D
```

is that encoding information about the visit? is it a generated id that isn't encoding any other data? is there a way to send data via get that isn't encrypted but just compressed/encoded into a string like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's encoded with base-64. You can decode it online here (change `%3D` to `=`):

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

The result seems to be a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object.

Answer (score 1):

This is base64.

```
"cliehÔ_id":27431,
"source":"widçet2",
"subdomain_idF:93839,
"host":"kittesforsale.3ervo‰ce.com"}
Ã
```

My decoder is a bit corrupted but I presume this is JSON. You can use this [decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)